# Tried other solutions but Boolean Modifier Difference not working

Tags: modifiers, screw-modifier

Still learning... Have use this operation several times.

Followed advice in other threads.... Flipped Normals, No doubles, trying to use screw to remove screw shape in cylinder.

Modifier:
Selected Cylinder, Operation - Difference, Object - Screw, Apply

Rtemoved screw and still have complete cylinder...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you enter Edit mode for the cylinder and press Ctrl+N with all selected to recalculate normals?

Comment: Alredy did that..even did the W menu and clicked on Flip Normals to make sure

Comment: Please upload a file. It will make it easier to find the mistake.

Comment: It's visible on the screenshot that normals are still oriented wrongly so it can be one of the problems. Try applying scale of the cylinder (Object mode > Ctrl+A > Scale), then recalculate normals. Uploaded file could help here as well, use [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and paste link either in comments or edit the question.

Comment: I added the file

Comment: Both objects have normals oriented inwards which is fixed with Ctrl+N with all selected in Edit mode. That's not the only problem, screwed mesh has very dense geometry which meets in the single [spot in the center of the screw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxvtB.jpg). This is non-manifold geometry which will never work right especially with Boolean. Try dissolving at least half of edges from the screwed mesh and converting central part to more solid mesh, probably screwing from scratch is easier.

Comment: Ended up deleting it all and starting over.. worked now..